# NameError ("name 'message' is not defined")

Tags: python, telegram-bot

The error is that when I choose: Samsung, Xiaomi or Huawei, such a NameError error appears ("name 'message' is not defined"). I tried to change their order and it turned out that there was an error when I select something other than the last.The problem is that this part of the code does not work **"bot.edit_message_text (chat_id = call.message.chat.id, message_id = call.message.message_id, text = "Scegliete cosa vi interessa:",reply_markup = None)"**

```
import telebot
import config
from telebot import types

bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.TOKEN)
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])

def welcome(message):

    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    item1 = types.KeyboardButton("Catalogo")
    item2 = types.KeyboardButton("Regole")
    markup.add(item1, item2)

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Benvenuto, {0.first_name}!\nIo sono - <b>{1.first_name}</b>.".format(message.from_user, bot.get_me()),
    parse_mode='html', reply_markup=markup)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])

def risposta(message):
    if message.chat.type == 'private':
        if message.text == "Catalogo":

            markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width = 1)

            item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("iPhone", callback_data = "iPhone")
            item2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Samsung", callback_data = "Samsung")
            item3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Huawei", callback_data = "Huawei")
            item4 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Xiaomi", callback_data = "Xiaomi")

            markup.add(item1, item2, item3, item4)
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Scegliete cosa vi interessa:", reply_markup=markup)


        elif message.text == "Regole":
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, " 1)Dovete vivere a Roma.\n2)Il pagamento viene effettuato dopo aver scielto il telefono.\n3)")

        else :
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Scusate non ho capito")

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)

def callback_inline(call):
    try:        
        if call.message:

            if call.data == "Samsung" :

                markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width = 3)

                item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Model", callback_data = "Model")
                item2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Model", callback_data = "Model")
                item3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Model", callback_data = "Model")
                item4 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Model", callback_data = "Model")
                item5 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Model", callback_data = "Model")
                item6 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Model", callback_data = "Model")
                item7 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Model", callback_data = "Model")
                item8 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Model", callback_data = "Model")
                item9 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Model", callback_data = "Model")
                item10 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Model", callback_data = "Model")
                item11 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Model", callback_data = "Model")
                item12 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Model", callback_data = "Model")
                item13 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Model", callback_data = "Model")
                item14 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Model", callback_data = "Model")
                item15 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Model", callback_data = "Model")
                item16 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Model", callback_data = "Model")
                item17 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Model", callback_data = "Model")
                item18 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Model", callback_data = "Model")

                markup.add(item1, item2, item3, item4, item5, item6, item7, item8, item9, item10, item11, item12, item13, item14, item15, item16, item17, item18)
                bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "Scegliete il modello:", reply_markup=markup)

            if call.data == "Xiaomi":

                markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width = 3)

                item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Model", callback_data = "Model")
                item2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Model", callback_data = "Model")
                item3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Model", callback_data = "Model")
                item4 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Model", callback_data = "Model")
                item5 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Model", callback_data = "Model")
                item6 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Model", callback_data = "Model")
                item7 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Model", callback_data = "Model")
                item8 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Model", callback_data = "Model")
                item9 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Model", callback_data = "Model")
                item10 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Model", callback_data = "Model")

                markup.add(item1, item2, item3, item4, item5, item6, item7, item8, item9, item10)
                bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "Scegliete il modello:", reply_markup=markup)

            if call.data == "Huawei":

                markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width = 3)

                item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Model", callback_data = "Model")
                item2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Model", callback_data = "Model")
                item3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Model", callback_data = "Model")
                item4 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Model", callback_data = "Model")
                item5 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Model", callback_data = "Model")
                item6 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Model", callback_data = "Model")
                item7 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Model", callback_data = "Model")
                item8 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Model", callback_data = "Model")
                item9 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Model", callback_data = "Model")
                item10 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Model", callback_data = "Model")

                markup.add(item1, item2, item3, item4, item5, item6, item7, item8, item9, item10)
                bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "Scegliete il modello:", reply_markup=markup)

            if call.data == 'iPhone':

                markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width = 3)

                item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("iPhone 11 Pro Max", callback_data = "iPhone 11 Pro Max")
                item2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("iPhone 11 Pro", callback_data = "iPhone 11 Pro")
                item3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("iPhone 11", callback_data = "iPhone 11")
                item4 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("iPhone XS Max", callback_data = "iPhone XS Max")
                item5 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("iPhone XS", callback_data = "iPhone XS")
                item6 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("iPhone XR", callback_data = "iPhone XR")
                item7 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("iPhone X", callback_data = "iPhone X")
                item8 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("iPhone 8 Plus", callback_data = "iPhone 8 Plus")
                item9 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("iPhone 8", callback_data = "iPhone 8")
                item10 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("iPhone 7 Plus", callback_data = "iPhone 7 Plus")
                item11 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("iPhone 7", callback_data = "iPhone 7")

                markup.add(item1, item2, item3, item4, item5, item6, item7, item8, item9, item10, item11)
                bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "Scegliete il modello:", reply_markup=markup)

            else :
                bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "Scusate non ho capito")


            bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id, text="Scegliete cosa vi interessa:",
            reply_markup=None)

    except Exception as e:
        print(repr(e))

bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: First of all, it is bad practice to catch all errors and just print them. If you really really want to completely ignore errors it is still better to print the full traceback using `traceback.print_exc`

Comment: The error cited in your title implies that you *directly* access a variable named `message`. The line you point to does not do so. Does the error originate in some other code *called* by this line? Does it originate at the later line ``bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Scusate non ho capito")``? Please post the entire stack trace.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi https://pastebin.com/M3LQpr3A all my code

Comment: That's not what I asked for. Please post the entire stack trace.

Comment: Please share a [mcve], as well as the **entire** error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the error is actually in the line `bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Scusate non ho capito")` in the else block for the iphone condition. The object `message` doesn't exist, which produces the NameError you're receiving. Changing it to `call.message.chat.id` to match the other parts of the code should fix it.

Comment: This resolve the problem , but now if i choose  iphone  or something else i always recive "Scusate non ho capito" of the else condition.

Comment: I'm not familiar with telegram-bot so I can't say why your object may not be triggering any of the other conditions. I'd look into what `call.data` actually looks like on a test case and maybe consider posting a new question with just that.